# how to retrieve an array into one class from a different class

Tags: java, arrays

I have a class where I made an array of the planets.

```
private final static Planet[]       
    {
        new Planet("Mercury"),
        new Planet("Venus"),
        new Planet("Earth"),
        new Planet("Mars"),
        new Planet("Jupiter"),
        new Planet("Saturn"),
        new Planet("Uranus"),
        new Planet("Neptune")
        
    };
```

and I need to retrieve it into another class.

```
public float getPlanetMass()
    {
        
        
    }
```

How exactly would I go about this?

Comment: Making the Planet class public is one way to do this. Another would be to research how an ``enum`` (enumeration) works.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a public method in a class to return the planets and another class that will call that method to get the list. Something like below :

```
public class Test {

    private Planet[] getPlanets(){
        Planet[] planets = new Planet[8];
        int index = 0;
        for(String name : Arrays.asList("Mercury", "Venus", "Earth", "Mars", "Jupiter", "Saturn", "Uranus", "Neptune")) {
            planets[index++] = new Planet(name);
        }
        return planets;
    }
    
    static class PlanetClient{
        public static void main(String args[]) {
            Test test = new Test();
            Planet[] planets = test.getPlanets();
            System.out.println("Planets are " + Arrays.toString(planets));
        }
    }
    
    class Planet {
        String name;
        Planet(String name){
            this.name = name;
        }
        
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return this.name;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to do this but instead of creating an array you could create an `Enum` called `Planet` or even an enum called `StandardPlanet` or `TerrestialPlanet` that implements an interface called `Plant`. This way the enum uses the multiton pattern, you can reference these elements publicly, and you're not creating non-private mutable objects.

```java
public interface Planet {

}
```

```java
public enum TerrestialPlanet implements Plant {
    EARTH,
    MARS,
    // etc
}
```

```java
Planet planet = TerrestialPlanet.EARTH;
```